# Unity Android App crashing

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, crash

My app crashes on my title scene (my second scene). The start code for the scene is this

```
 AnimatorRef = GetComponent<Animator>();
```

and in another script this

```
void Start () {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PlayBoo") == 1)
        {
            Death.Play();
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlayBoo", 0);
        }
    }
```

there is a scene before it that initialises the player prefs

```
void Start () {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlayBoo", 0);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }
```

there is another method that loads the scene. there is an idle animation that plays at  the start but it has no problems loading in the editor.

Comment: can you please share your crash logs?

Comment: I don't know how to get them. I am building the apk and running it on my phone.

Comment: Plugin your device and Run below command (after go to the androidsdk-platformtools using cd command)
$ adb logcat | grep -e "Unity"